# macOS Swift 3 - Handling notification alert action button

Tags: swift, macos

I'm new to Swift (but not to programming). I have simple app that provides an alert based on specific conditionals. I would like to execute a function (or even just set a variable) when one of the buttons is pressed. Ideally, I just need one button, but if for whatever reason, only the `notification.actionButtonTitle` can have a handler, that's fine with me.

My notification code is currently in a Swift file as a helper.

```
import Foundation

    class NotificationHelper {
      static func sampleNotification(notification: NSUserNotification) {
        let notificationCenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.default

        notification.identifier = "unique-id-123"
        notification.hasActionButton = true
        notification.otherButtonTitle = "Close"
        notification.actionButtonTitle = "Show"
        notification.title = "Hello"
        notification.subtitle = "How are you?"
        notification.informativeText = "This is a test"
        notificationCenter.deliver(notification)
      }
    }
```

Currently in `AppDelegate`, this is defined:

```
let notification = NSUserNotification()
```

…and I call the notification like this:

```
NotificationHelper.sampleNotification(notification: notification)
```

The resulting notification works, as you can see in the screenshot below. However, I cannot seem to listen to the button action. I have tried adding this to the `AppDelegate` as well as the `NotificationHelper` file, but I did not have any success with it:

```
func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didActivateNotification notification: NSUserNotification) {
  print("checking notification response")

}
```

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Thanks!

[image: Sample macOS notification using Swift3]

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to assign something as the `delegate` of the `NSUserNotificationCenter`:

`NSUserNotificationCenter.default.delegate = self`

If you add this to your `AppDelegate` and make your `AppDelegate` conform to [NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsusernotificationcenterdelegate):

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

}
```